# Format a MySQL date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a column in my table of type `datetime`. I want to display them in a particular format, so I tried using this:

```
echo date( 'm/d/Y - g:h A', strtotime($dateFromMySQL) );
```

...which just messes everything up, completely.

---

If I simply do `echo $dateFromMySQL;` (in a loop), I get this:

> 2011-09-10 01:03:04
>   2011-09-10 00:52:47
>   2011-09-10 00:40:26
>   and so on...

...which is correct.

---

If I do `echo strtotime($dateFromMySQL);`, I get this:

> 1315630984
>   1315630367
>   1315629626
>   and so on...

...which might be correct. I wouldn't know.

---

However, when I do `echo date( 'm/d/Y - g:h:s A', strtotime($dateFromMySQL) );`, I get this:

> 09/10/2011 - 1:01:04 AM
>   09/10/2011 - 12:12:47 AM
>   09/10/2011 - 12:12:26 AM
>   and so on...

...which is obviously wrong.

---

So, **my question is**, what am I doing wrong?
Am I somehow not using `strtotime` and `date` correctly?

Comment: try createfromformat not strtotime and manually put the input date format. From php manual, "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. "

Comment: Be sure to check out the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `m/d/Y - g:i:s A`.

`h` - hour
`i` - minutes

Answer (score 2):

It should be m/d/Y - g:**i**:s A

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong date format of `h`

correct behavior

```
date( 'm/d/Y - g:i:s A' ...
```

**what is `h & i` in PHP date function?**

> h = 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
>   i = Minutes with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You ask for the hour in 12 h format and then for the hour in 24 h format.

Use `'g:i:s'` instead of `'g:h:s'`.

Additionally, I get a warning on trying:

> PHP Warning:  strtotime(): **It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for
>   'CEST/2.0/DST' instead** in Command line code on line 1

so this might be - or become - an additional issue.

Comment: Thanks. I always use `date_default_timezone_set()` at the beginning of my scripts.