# Change date format in php retrieved from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in mysql which stores the dates. So in mysql the dates are stored in `Y-M-D` format. However on retrieval i want to view change that format to `D-M-Y` . I read online at a few places and i found the date() in php, [Date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357461/format-a-mysql-date-in-php). But they are generally for timestamp, also in many cases people had recommended to split the variable by `-` and then changing position.

My question is that, is splitting the variable the only option here or do we have any built in function that does that for us?

Comment: `strtotime` and `date` are exactly what you need for this. Unless you explicity create an obscene time string, the `strtotime` function should accurately parse your date. You should at least try it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this should work for you, check here http://codepad.org/YdZQzgXR

```
<?
   $date = '2012-12-30';
   echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do that on the PHP side or on the MySQL side.

On the MySQL side you could use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

or from a field:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM articles;
```

On the PHP side you have more tools:

- use a database abstraction layer (PDO, MDB, etc.)
- parse the returned time with [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) and then use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to format it
- split as you mentioned
- ...

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities: PHP's strtotime() or let MySQL do the job!